# Convert StringWriter to string[]

Tags: c#

I had a requirement to create a `TextWriter` to populate some data. I used the `StringWriter` as a TextWriter and the business logic works fine.

I have a technical requirement that cannot be changed because it may break all the clients. I need to  an array of strings `string[]` from the `TextWriter` separated by line.

I tried with this but didn't work:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace TextWriterToArrayOfStringsDemo
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
            {
                writer.Write("A");
                writer.WriteLine();
                writer.Write("B");
            }

            string fullString = stringBuilder.ToString();
            string replaced = fullString.Replace('\n', '\r');
            string[] arrayOfString = replaced.Split('\r');

            // Returns false but should return true
            Console.WriteLine(arrayOfString.Length == 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Why replace the end-of-line characters? This will give you two line breaks if it ever generates `\r\n` (which I'd be surprised if it did). And can you give us more detail about what this does produce, i.e. what's still wrong with it?

Comment: The thing is that <code>writer.NewLine</code> contains a <code>\r\n</code>. I need to get the content of the writer separated by <code>\r\n</code> and not include either <code>\r</code> or <code>\n</code>.

Comment: Jeff or John's answers are probably the way to go, but a simple way to fix yours is `string replaced = fullString.Replace("\r\n", "\n");` and `string[] arrayOfString = replaced.Split('\n');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `Environment.NewLine` to split rather than `'\n'`:

```
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
        {
            writer.Write("A");
            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.Write("B");
        }

        string fullString = stringBuilder.ToString();
        string[] newline = new string[] { Environment.NewLine };
        string[] arrayOfString = fullString.Split(newline, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Returns false but should return true
        Console.WriteLine(arrayOfString.Length == 2);
```

Comment: StringBuilder has (at least now it has) a NewLine property, so you can avoid the dependency on Environment:

```
writer.ToString().Split(writer.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix would be to use a Regex split:

```
string[] arrayOfString = 
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(stringBuilder.ToString(), "\r?\n")
```

Comment: I think this solution is more elegant. But the other is cleaner and more descriptive. How would you call the `\r?\n`?

Comment: It's just a regular expression pattern that means essentially "any 0 or 1 instances of \r followed by a \n", so it splits the string on any of those instances. This example is only necessary if you're not sure which platform the text file was created on as Linux/Unix text files will use \n and Windows will use \r\n for their line endings.